# NVidia Graphics Card Issue. GeForce 820M

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, intel-graphics, hybrid-graphics, nvidia-geforce

As i had windows 10 with GeForce graphics card, I installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS uninstalling windows. Now I have an issue (i.e) when I pass this command

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

my results be like

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
```

it isn't showing my NVidia grpahics driver. I tried all the answers given in ubuntu forums and stack exchanges still i couldn't get rid off it. Need solved solutions.

Comment: I think what you should type is:

`lspci | grep 3D`

Comment: Yes Mr. @RifazNahiyan . Now it shows me   09:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)  does this mean I have installed my graphics driver??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal and execute :

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
```

Output shows something like :

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 3501
Kernel driver in use: i915

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev a2)
Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 3501
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Now you can see all the graphics drivers currently being in use.

In case it does not show `Kernel driver in use: nvidia` ...

Install the NVIDIA drivers and Optimus support - execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

**Update adressing your response that you have issues with the drivers :**

Step 1 : Uninstall every NVIDIA related software that is currently installed.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On the login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
Enter user name and password - execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Step 2 : Install the latest official NVIDIA drivers that support NVIDIA 820M.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On the login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
Enter user name and password - execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Comment: bur mine doesn't belong to 860M, mine is 820M. Will it be compatible with nvidia-352??

Comment: @Karthik : This is just an example from a machine that has NVIDIA GTX 860M graphics, most important is : "Kernel driver in use: nvidia" and nvidia-352 is the drivers version which is compatible with 820M as well. :)

Comment: Thanks Mr. @cl-netbox it is showing me "Kernel driver in use: nouveau" i'll install and tell you

Comment: Mr. Cl-netbox I have a problem now after installing nvidia-352. After rebooting my screen remains totally blank even backlite is turned but CPU busy running lights are working. What could be the problem?  This happened more number of times. Should i reinstall the OS again

Comment: Ok Mr. Cl-netbox I'll be waiting

Comment: Yea stay tuned sir. I'll update it soon

Comment: I couldn't get this part "Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the E key.
Add nouveau.modeset=0 to the end of the linux line - press F10 to boot." Could you please clarify??

Comment: @Karthik : It means : select the Ubuntu entry - press the E key and write the parameter at the end of the line beginning with linux ... of course with a space between the last sign and nouveau.modeset=0 ! :)

Comment: Yes am getting it installing driver I'll update you

Comment: Still I have the  Same problem. Am trying it again. If you have any other solution pls do give it anyway half of the answer helped me to boot to gui

Comment: @Karthik : This should work - please check whether there are settings in BIOS to activate the NVIDIA card or the switchable mode and do not connect an external monitor before or during the installation process.  You can switch between the intel and NVIDIA graphics from NVIDIA X Server Settings -> PRIME Profiles. :)

Comment: Actually there are no settings like that in BIOS

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help you provide cl-netbox, I managed to instal Ubuntu on my xps after a struggle but this same issue of booting into a black screen despite all the attempts is still unsolved. Mine is Nvidia GTX 960. Any updates?

Comment: @azyaser : You're welcome - no, unfortunately not and as I said before, it really should have worked, you might consider contacting DELL support, maybe there are some hidden BIOS settings or something else DELL specific - DELL XPS 13 developer edition notebook for instance comes with Ubuntu pre-installed. :)

Comment: Can you please at least confirm whether to use nvidia352 or nvidia-361?

Comment: @azyaser : As you have very new graphics hardware, I recommend to install the latest official NVIDIA drivers, which are nvidia-361 - these drivers are included in the coming Ubuntu 16.04 LTS release ! :)